# How would you name import and export functions in Java?

Tags: java, naming

I have a Java class that handles import and export of data. It started out as a simple

```
private void export() {
}
private void import() {
}
```

Of course, I wrote the export first, committed it, and then went on to write the import. But import is a keyword in Java - I can't use that as a function name. So I go back and rename both methods. I usually end up with

```
private void doExport() {
}
private void doImport() {
}
```

which is both ugly and feels contrived. What do you think of these names? Got any better suggestions?

Note: I'm asking now, because it's now happened thrice and that keyword is getting quite annoying.

Comment: I realize this method is quite subjective. I hope it's not off-topic here.

Comment: This might be subjective, but it's still directly programming related, so I'd argue it belongs on StackOverflow and not here.

Comment: I don't think SO would appreciate this kind of question.

Comment: See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/350/the-six-subjective-question-guidelines-enforcement-notice. You could change your question to match 1, your question might meet 2, I guess it will meet 3; it meets 4, 5 and 6...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would prefer something like this:

```
private void importData(){}
private void exportData(){}
```

If you now would use this Class as an API you can do something like this:

```
dataUtil.importData();
```

With the CodeCompletion of the IDE, the differences are more visible if this methods wouldn't start the same way.

Comment: I agree, this is much better than `doImport`/`doExport` for most cases. Good answer!

Answer (score 1):

This is the same problem as with all keywords in programming languages. But the problem is easy, just chose another name.

How about this?

```
private void dataExport() {
}
private void dataImport() {
}
```